# Need Better Search Conditions on Duplicate VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, sosl

I have an apex class that brings up duplicates when a user enters in an account name in the search box on the visualforce page. Right now, the search takes the **exact letters** written into the search text box. What I would like to happen is to have the word being searched on be somewhere in the name of the account and not necessarily starts with the word. I would also like to put conditions in so that if a user enters a name and a street address it will search on both of them combined and bring up all accounts that have the address or the name. Thanks!

Full Class code below:

```
public class AccountDupeCatch {

public boolean errormsg=false;
public String AccountId=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
public String aname;
public List<Account> chkdup;
public Account newaccount= new Account();

 public AccountDupeCatch(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
 }

 public account getnewaccount() {
 return newaccount;
 }
 public account getexistingaccount() {
 if (chkdup!= NULL)
 {
 if(chkdup.size()>0)
     return chkdup[0];
 else
     return null;
 }
 else
     return null;
}

public list<account> getexistingaccountlist()
{
 if (chkdup!= NULL)
 {
 if(chkdup.size()>0)
     return chkdup;
 else
     return null;
 }
 else
     return null;
}

public pagereference Next() {

chkdup=[Select    name,id,recordtype.name,CustomerMasterID__c,shippingstreet,shippingcity,shippingstate from Account where Name=:newaccount.name];
   if(chkdup.size()==0)
 {
  String aname=newaccount.Name;
  Pagereference newaccount1 = new Pagereference('/001/e?nooverride=true&acc2='+aname+'');
  return newaccount1;
 }
 else
{
   errormsg=true;
   return null;
}

}

public pagereference SelectName() {

Pagereference chkdup = new Pagereference('/' + chkdup[0].Id);
return chkdup;
}

public boolean geterrormsg() {
return errormsg;
}
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
  <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountDupeCatch">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name">
   <apex:form >
         Enter the Account Name Here
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:inputField value="{!NewAccount.Name}"/>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" value="click here to proceed" status="status"/>

     <!-- Display error message -->
         <apex:pagemessage strength="2" title="Duplicate!!" severity="error" detail="This Account Name Already Exists !!!" rendered="{!errormsg}"/><!-- End of error message -->
           <apex:pageblocktable rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(existingaccountlist))}" value="{!existingaccountlist}" var="acct">
                          <apex:column headervalue="Select">
                                   <apex:commandlink action="{!SelectName}">
                                       <input type="radio" name="AccountSel" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.RadioButtonValue}')"/>
                                   </apex:commandlink>                                         
                          </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Account Name"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.Name}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Type"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.recordtype.name}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Customer ID"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.CustomerMasterID__c}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="Shipping Street"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingstreet}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="City"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingcity}"/>  </apex:column>
                          <apex:column headervalue="State"> <apex:outputtext value="{!acct.shippingstate}"/>  </apex:column>
           </apex:pageblocktable>
 </apex:form>
```

Comment: Did you write the code in the question, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: Be careful with this code since it assumes that your address match is perfect... what if your code searches "123 Main Street" and finds "123 Main Street Suite 100" when you really meant Suite 200?  This would overwrite the incorrect account, when it really is not a dup...  You may be better served showing your user the list of accounts your query returns and asking them "did you really mean one of these?"

Comment: My question was pretty broad but Nathan Williams had the perfect answer. I didn't personally write the code I just modified it for my org. Thanks to everyone for responding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily change

```
[Select name,id,recordtype.name,CustomerMasterID__c,shippingstreet,shippingcity,shippingstate from Account where Name=:newaccount.name];
```

to

```
Database.query('Select name,id,recordtype.name,CustomerMasterID__c,shippingstreet,shippingcity,shippingstate from Account where Name like \'% + newaccount.name + '%\'' OR (ShippingStreet like \'% + newaccount.shippingstreet + '%\' AND ShippingCity like \'% + newaccount.shippingcity + '%\' AND ShippingState like \'% + newaccount.shippingstate + '%\'));
```

That will look for any accounts where:

1. the `name` they enter is contained in the name field of any existing account
   OR
2. the `shippingstreet` is contained in an existing account's street address AND the `shippingcity` is contained in an existing account's city AND the `shippingstate` is contained in an existing account's state

... the % signs in conjuntion with `like` act like a wildcard search and the right combination of boolean AND/OR logic helps (my AND/OR was based on what i understood you wanted, but can be easily tweaked)